# How to keep input text focus still when clicked on div?

Tags: javascript, text, input, focus

Just like title says, I'm trying to keep the input text focus still when click on one div.

Specifically I'm trying something like what happens in Google Livesearch (Not Instant Search) (When you type there, shows a ten items list.) (I can't put an image).

When you click on "Google Search", still keeps input text focus.

I'm trying but always lose the input text focus.

Someone knows how to achieve this?.

P.S: With click I mean the mousedown event.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refocus on your text input when a mousedown event is caught on your division.

Here is a quick example using jQuery:

```
$("#my-division").on("mousedown", function (evt) {
    $("#my-input").focus();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution:

First, store the last focused element:

```
var lastFormElementFocused = 'my-first-element-id';
$(document).on('focus', '.your-class', function() {
        lastFormElementFocused = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(lastFormElementFocused);
    });
```

After that, in your onClick event:

```
$(document).on('click', "div.your-class", function() {
        $("#" + lastFormElementFocused).focus();
        var element = $(document.activeElement);
        // Do with 'element' what you want
    });
```

> Note that you need to have an assigned id in each element you focus.